# React Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs

I receive an error while running my application in React. There are lots of questions with this error but I do not how to solve it. When I press the link, it directs to Login component. 'http://localhost:3000/login'

This is the error which I got on the site:

'Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.'

Here is my LoginPage:

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // reset login status
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.logout());

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            submitted: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h2>Login</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { auth: state.auth };
}
const loginComp = connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage);
export { loginComp as LoginPage };
```

And this is the routing part.

```
render() {
  const { alert } = this.props;
  return (

  <Router history={history} >
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute path="/" name="Home" component={DefaultLayout} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  );
}
```

And that one is DefaultLayout:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';

import {
  AppAside,
  AppBreadcrumb,
  AppFooter,
  AppHeader,
  AppSidebar,
  AppSidebarFooter,
  AppSidebarForm,
  AppSidebarHeader,
  AppSidebarMinimizer,
  AppSidebarNav,
} from '@coreui/react';
// sidebar nav config
import navigation from '../../_nav';
// routes config
import routes from '../../routes';
import DefaultAside from './DefaultAside';
import DefaultFooter from './DefaultFooter';
import DefaultHeader from './DefaultHeader';

class DefaultLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <AppHeader fixed>
          <DefaultHeader />
        </AppHeader>
        <div className="app-body">
          <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
            <AppSidebarHeader />
            <AppSidebarForm />
            <AppSidebarNav navConfig={navigation} {...this.props} />
            <AppSidebarFooter />
            <AppSidebarMinimizer />
          </AppSidebar>
          <main className="main">
            <AppBreadcrumb appRoutes={routes}/>
            <Container fluid>
              <Switch>
                {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                    return route.component ? (<Route key={idx} path={route.path} exact={route.exact} name={route.name} render={props => (
                        <route.component {...props} />
                      )} />)
                      : (null);
                  },
                )}
                <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />
              </Switch>
            </Container>
          </main>
          <AppAside fixed hidden>
            <DefaultAside />
          </AppAside>
        </div>
        <AppFooter>
          <DefaultFooter />
        </AppFooter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DefaultLayout;
```

The problem could be somewhere else other than this jsx??

Comment: you're getting maximum depth error after redirecting ?

Comment: and about which link you're talking about ?

Comment: I wrote it wrong probably, I do not do any redirection. There are only 2 routes in in the upper most component. I will update my question.

Comment: your question title is misleading

Comment: What error you get ? I'm still unable to understand

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Paste code of DefaultLayout

Comment: can you try commenting out this line of code and see if it works? `this.props.dispatch(userActions.logout());` its in your login constructor.

Comment: I commented it out but nothing changed.

Comment: Can the problem be somewhere else??

Comment: where is dashboard? There's setState invoked by render somewhere in your components

Comment: dashboard is routed to Dashboard component and there is so much things going on that component. You think execution comes to that part??
By the way, I commented out that <Redirect> line in DefaultLayout rended method.

Comment: I developed the app from free "Reactjs Core UI" . Here is the [link](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template)

Comment: If you share it over github or codesandbox it would be easier to find the bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not going to believe me maybe but I solved the issue by changing the order of Route tags. First one is the tag with path "/login" and it works correctly.

Comment: I had the same thing, with no dispatches/setstates anywhere in the constructor. Did you run into any problems later or find out why this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you are calling         this.props.dispatch(userActions.logout());
in your constructor and that is not a good place to update the application state, because that will make the component to re-render before it gets mounted and each time it wants to re-render you are again calling the function in its constructor and setting the state so it gets into a loop where it calls the setState again and again, its better to put this.props.dispatch(userActions.logout()); in a lifeCycle method like componentDidMount(){} so each time your component gets mounted, your logout action gets called and updated the application state.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, i understood that calling setState inside arrow functions (that is, function written in ES6 format) repeatedly causes this error. Therefore, as much as much possible i started using ES5 format functions only.